Why this happens when i delete the Center Widget Before SingleChildScrollView?
I have this piece of code :
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: ContainerStyles.gradientBoxDecoration,
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
............

I dont get it if i remove the Center Widget it seperates my screen in half and let the other half white(without my container color) ,my guessing is that Center widget by default it takes the full height and width?
It works like Expanded ?
I dont get it how it works , im trying to avoid bugs in the future so im trying to undertand it better.
Any help will be appreciate :)

Can you add full code here?

As I think, your Column size is not long enough, so the ScrollView only displays half the screen. You can replace Center with Expanded.

I tried it with a simple text also inside it ,it does the same thing so the problem is somehow in that specific Widget series/turn ..

I did but it says that this :
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a
RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.
Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget.
Typically,
Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Padding widget.

Also still it leaves some white screen in the bottom of my screen.
